# App Theme Changing not Effecting on the First MainActivity.its reamain darkmode every first time app is lunched .after navigation its Theme Update

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android

I have set the Theme in MainActivty DayTime mode using this line   `AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;` when the app lunches the app theme mode not updating the ui of daytime when i navigate to other  page then the theme will change to daytime theme and back to MainActivity also update the Theme to Daytime.The problem is why not Theme update on app lunches to Daytime even i have write the line in oncreate of mainActivity`AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo`. I have Try to Recreate() activity and refress Activity Not working.

NightMode Style

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orangeDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orangeDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

NightMode Colors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
  <color name="colorAccent">#ffffff</color>
  <color name="orange">#ff8200</color>
  <color name="orangeDark">#f77000</color>
  <color name="daynight_textColor">#ffffff</color>
  <color name="switchColor">#BC2F1D</color>
  
</resources>
```

DayTime Style

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orangeDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orangeDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

DayTime Colors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
  <color name="colorAccent">#ff8200</color>
  <color name="orange">#ff8200</color>
  <color name="orangeDark">#f77000</color>
  <color name="daynight_textColor">#100c08</color>
  <color name="switchColor">#BC2F1D</color>
  <color name="vividCerise">#da1d81</color>
  <color name="smokyBlack">#100c08</color>
  <color name="indigo_500">#3f51b5</color>
  <color name="indigo_700">#303f9f</color>
  <color name="cyan_500">#00bcd4</color>
  <color name="hint_color">#42000000</color>
</resources>
```

Menifist Theme Settings

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

In MainActivity Setting the Theme

```
 AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```

Main Activity Attribute

```
  [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop, ConfigurationChanges = (Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode))]
```

Comment: You can try to use `Delegate.SetLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo);` code in the `OnCreate` method of `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not explained properly. What you want if you want to set theme programatically inside onCreate callback then you have to set theme before calling super.onCreate() like

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen)
}
```

Setting theme in activity will work for that activity. If you want to update theme for entire application set in Application class
Add application class say MyApplication extending Application
add MyApplication to Manifest
and in MyApplication onCreate set your theme. But

```
override fun onCreate() {
   setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
   super.onCreate()
}
```

Manifest

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication">
```

Comment: I want to chnage theme of my app but its not working when we change theme in on create .but when we navigate to other page then theme is updated  in whole app.why theme is not updating  without navigating to other page.im changing theme in MainActivity

Comment: then set theme at application level. you might be using different activities for different pages.

Comment: how i set  please explain

Comment: Still not updating the app theme of MainActivity